# discord.js How to ban someone when they join if they match a specific ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to check to see if a user is a specific user when they join my discord server and then ban them if they are. I am pretty new to this and this code is not working. any help?

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    if (member.id === "401539231828148224") {
        member.ban;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[`GuildMember#ban`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) is a method, not a property. You'll have to use parentheses. (`()`)

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    if (member.id === "401539231828148224") {
        member.ban({ reason: "Reason for the ban." });
    }
});
```

---

Note that you need to activate the `Server Members Intent` in your application's `Bot` tab.
[image]